# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angularjs-scope, spree

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

    myapp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
      $interpolateProvider
        .startSymbol('{[')
        .endSymbol(']}');
    });

    myapp.controller('CanvasControls', function($scope) {
        function1($scope);
        function2($scope);
     });

    This code integrate with rails and working in development fine but in production mode it gives below errors.
```

Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:

```
Uncaught Error: $injector:modulerr
```

/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp

Answer (score 1):

> working in development fine but in production mode it gives below
>   errors

Guess in production you are compressing the code.And I presume you have to add  `$scope` like this
Hope this will help

```
// Changed here Added String '$scope'
    myapp.controller('CanvasControls',['$scope', function($scope) { 
            function1($scope);
            function2($scope);
         }]);
```

**EDIT**

If you have not modified the .config part please try by making following change.

```
customInterpolationApp.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider){
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
}]);
```

[More](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr) about such error

Comment: did you also checked the .config part?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error added extra `]` in controller

```
myapp.controller('CanvasControls', function($scope) {
     function1($scope);
     function2($scope);
}]);// remove ']' from here
```

or use mini-fist way

```
myapp.controller('CanvasControls', ['$scope',function($scope) {
     function1($scope);
     function2($scope);
}]);
```

and you may mismatch  module name `myapp` in  controller and in html `ng-app="myapp"`

Comment: check spelling in controller and view for 'myapp' (case sensitive )

Comment: Thanks  @shaishab roy mini-fist way  working for me now.